# How to change theme in ASP.Net MVC 5 based on querystring value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, themes

I want to change MVC theme dynamically based on querystring parameter in the url.

Eg:

1. localhost/WBE/Search/1
2. localhost/WBE/Search/2
3. localhost/WBE/Search/3

Here 1,2,3 are my customer keys and i have several customers who needs different themes in my websites. So, how can i change the layout in my website based on this key.

Awaiting for your reply.

Regards,
Mallikharjun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could set the layout dynamically in your controller action

```
public ActionResult Search(int customer)
{
  string layout = ... // function which get layout name with your customer id

  var viewModel = ... // function which get model

  return View("Search", layout, viewModel);
}
```

**Edit :**

I think if you want a better solution to change the layout in all view you must create an ActionAttributeFilter which will intercept the result and inject the layout in the viewresult

Your filter :

```
public class LayoutChooserAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _userLayoutSessionKey = "UserLayout";


    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);


        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        // Only if it's a ViewResult
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = GetUserLayout(filterContext);
        }
    }

    private string GetUserLayout(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_userLayoutSessionKey] == null)
        {
            // I stock in session to avoid having to start processing every view
            filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_userLayoutSessionKey] = ...; // process which search the layout
        }
        return (string)filterContext.HttpContext.Session[_userLayoutSessionKey];
    }

}
```

Your action become :

```
[LayoutChooser]
public ActionResult Search(int customer)
{
  var viewModel = ... // function which get model

  return View("Search", viewModel);
}
```

If you want that the attribute is present in all actions, in **FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters** static method you can add your filter :

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        ...
        filters.Add(new LayoutChooserAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean i want to this change to be done _ViewStart.html page layout property...Since, this layout should acts like master page for every theme. Please guide me....

Comment: You want select the layout in begin and then use the same layout everywhere in application for the customer ?

Comment: Yes,exactly the same i want...please help me with a clean example

Comment: Excuse me for my late reply, I edited my post with generic example